# Blazor binding to a nested controls value

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a page control, with a control called MyControl, and inside that is a 3rd party control called Autocomplete.

In MyControl,  I've setup the inner Autocomplete control to bind to propertiers in MyControl:

```
<Autocomplete 
              @bind-SelectedValue="@SelectedValue"
              @bind-SelectedText="@SelectedText">
</Autocomplete>

@code {
  [Parameter] public int SelectedValue { get; set; }
  [Parameter] public EventCallback<int> SelectedValueChanged { get; set; }

  [Parameter] public string SelectedText { get; set; }
  [Parameter] public EventCallback<string> SelectedTextChanged { get; set; }
}
```

In My page, I want to bind MyControl to properties on my page, but the properties on my page are not getting updated. Is this implementation correct?

```
<MyControl @bind-SelectedText="SelectedText"></MyControl >

@code 
{
  [Parameter] public int SelectedValue { get; set; }
   
  [Parameter] public string SelectedText { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to invoke the `EventCallback` whenever there is an update to the variables so that the parent component can get the changes. And since `Autocomplete` is a 3rd party component and maybe you don't want to customize it, you can invoke the changes from within the setters.

MyControl.razor:

```razor
<Autocomplete
    @bind-SelectedValue="@selectedValue"
    @bind-SelectedText="@selectedText">
</Autocomplete>

@code {

    private int selectedValue
    {
        get => SelectedValue;
        set
        {
            SelectedValue = value;
            SelectedValueChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
        }
    }
    [Parameter] public int SelectedValue { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<int> SelectedValueChanged { get; set; }

    private string selectedText
    {
        get => SelectedText;
        set
        {
            SelectedText = value;
            SelectedTextChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
        }
    }
    [Parameter] public string SelectedText { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<string> SelectedTextChanged { get; set; }
}
```

MyPage.razor:
The parent component don't need to have the variables as `Parameter` unless necessary.

```razor
<MyControl @bind-SelectedText="SelectedText"
           @bind-SelectedValue="SelectedValue"/>

@code 
{
  private int SelectedValue { get; set; }
  private string SelectedText { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Man thank you for this! This solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just having the `EventCallback` in `MyControl` allows 2-way binding syntax, but it must be invoked to actually send the udpated value to `MyPage`, i.e. I don't think the 2-way binding will get passed to the parent.
Maybe try declaring both value and callback, so `Autocomplete` binds to the Parameters set implicitly in `MyPage` instead of 2-way binding to `MyControl`?

```
<Autocomplete 
    @SelectedValue=SelectedValue
    @SelectedValueChanged=SelectedValueChanged
</Autocomplete>
```